# I'm made up of down, what am I?

Tags: riddle

You see me all day
I'm sharp

I show you your way
But you show me what to show you

I exist, but not in your dimension
I'm made up of down

My older language is by rotation
But now through light
(though in the end it comes down to the same shocking tale)

I usually look a certain way
But I change at certain times
Into myself, my thin sibling, into time,
and into ambiguity
or something with which you grasp

What am I?

Comment: (inconspicuous Red Alert 2 voice): "time is running out, time, time is running out" Nope not a clock :)

Comment: wild guess maybe it will help someone, it might be a celestial core of some kind...

Comment: The first thing I thought when I read the title in the HNQ was, "duh, a down comforter or pillow!" but of course, things are never such simple

Comment: Other than "made up of down", it could be glasses, or any other material who is used to amplify/clarify sight

Comment: @nine9 https://youtu.be/IGvlw7qBoJQ?t=2m

Comment: @Bob precisely! :p

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are:

> A mouse pointer.

You see me all day

> We use computers a lot!

I'm sharp

> It's a pointer!

I show you your way
But you show me what to show you

> Indicates where your cursor is, but you control it.

I exist, but not in your dimension
I'm made up of down

> It's made of light, but also the absence of light... only exists virtually and is visible only in the context of the light from surrounding pixels.

My older language is by rotation
But now through light
(though in the end it comes down to the same shocking tale)

> Trackerballs used rotation, old mouse balls were also rotation based, but optical mice are now more common, although trackpads which also control pointers don't really fit this. But the rotation similarities don't stop there... Electron guns in CRTs 'cycled' through the scan lines. LCDs used polarization (a kind of rotation). Now it's usually LEDs. All these methods use electricity (shocking).

I usually look a certain way

> Pointer

But I change at certain times
Into myself, my thin sibling, into time,

> A pointer, the text-select 'I' icon, the waiting/clock/hourglass/spinner symbol

and into ambiguity
or something with which you grasp

> A question mark, the grabber hand.

What am I?

> Mousy cursor pointer type thing.

Comment: Rotation vs. light probably refers to older-style mice using a ball, while newer ones use lasers.

Comment: Haha, yes you're right... I've used a trackpad for so long I forgot mice existed (although I still call it a mouse pointer!) and I certainly forgot all about taking the ball out and removing the hardened grime from the nylon rollers, and blowing the other gubbins out before replacing the ball.. ahh, good times! Edited in some additional notes re. this, thanks :)

Comment: For "I exist, but not in your dimension I'm made up of down"--could this instead be a reference to mouse pointers existing on a 2D plane, and increasing Y-values (going "up") corresponding to "downward" movement?

Comment: A mouse pointer is an arrow. Arrows can be made using feathers. Feathers can be [down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather).

Comment: This answer makes the most sense, except for the "I'm made up of down" part... I'm thinking there must be a typo in that line of the riddle.

Comment: @joeytwiddle: although the feathers used in arrows are/were not down feathers -- those fundamentally don't work for the purpose. Which doesn't mean the riddle-setter knows this.

Comment: Yeah as @pabrams asked - what's with "I'm made up of down".   The closest I could come that would fit here is that when I made up my mind I click down...

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it is correct. Though let me explain what you missed: "I exist, but not in your dimension I'm made up of down" means what @MiloPrice touched on, it exists in a 2D plain. It is made of 1's and 0's, logic HIGH and logic LOW is the up and down, so that sentence is also a play on words.

Comment: The language does refer to mouse balls and lasers @GentlePurpleRain.

Comment: And "ambiguity" is actually the double-arrow when changing window borders. Well done @jhabbot.

Comment: As a bonus, "tale" refers to mouse tail :p

Comment: "Rotation" could also apply to paddles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paddle_(game_controller)

Comment: @nine9 Even after you explained it, I still don't understand how "I'm made up of down" applies.  If I understand the explanation of your analogy, "made up of down" would mean made up of zeroes, which doesn't seem right.  I would think it would need to read "I'm made up of up and down" in order to fit, but maybe I'm being thick...

Comment: @pabrams Yes, the original sentence would have been "I'm made up of up and down", but I compressed the sentence to create a play on words, where "up" is ambiguous in meaning, being the action of the sentence as well as the object. Of coarse, this ambiguity only becomes apparent when the reader has basically solved the riddle, so it's more of a misleading sentence in itself

Answer (score 11):

**You are:**

> An Up (or Down) Quark.

You see me all day:

> The little buggers are everywhere, in all matter. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

I'm sharp:

> Quarks are a tiny, like the edge of an absurdly sharp blade. Some people would consider Quarks to be smart, as they are explained and though about by Physicists (ie: sharp people).

I show you your way
But you show me what to show you:

> According to certain interpretations of Quantum Mechanics, the state of a quantum particle (ie: a Quark) is decided by whether it is observed or not. If it is unobserved, then it is in a state of Superposition, once it is observed its State Collapses.

I exist, but not in your dimension:

> Quarks are subatomic matter, they are *tiny*. Relatively speaking, humans are **huge**. Dimension here refers to size.

I'm made up of down:

> Hence Up or Down Quark (probably Up).

My older language is by rotation:

> [Quarks are imagined to 'spin' but this notion is misguided.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Spin)

But now through light:

> I can't explain this. It might have something to do with Quarks [color charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Strong_interaction_and_color_charge).

(though in the end it comes down to the same shocking tale):

> Quantum Mechanics is sometimes considered bizarre and shocking.

I usually look a certain way
But I change at certain times

> Again with Quantum State.

Into myself, my thin sibling, into time,
and into ambiguity
or something with which you grasp

> Changing states upon observation. 'Grasp' as in strong interaction.

Comment: I'm just going to point out that I am not a Physicist and my knowledge of this sort of thing is flaky. If you are a Physicist (or you know more about physics) and I made you cringe, then I sincerely apologize.

Comment: Physicist here; I cringed.

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of too when I saw the title, but the rest of the riddle quickly steered me away from that conclusion. =P

Answer (score 4):

You see me all day

> We look for direction constantly

I'm sharp

> Made up of points

I show you your way

> Uses magnetism to provide a constant bearing

But you show me what to show you

> By aligning the dial and the viewport

I exist, but not in your dimension

> Getting fuzzy here

I'm made up of down

> Technically magnets point the opposite direction. The end painted red is magnetized the opposite of north, which is why it is attracted to north.

My older language is by rotation

> Compasses once rotated

But now through light

> on your phone!

(though in the end it comes down to the same shocking tale)

> electromagnetism

I usually look a certain way

> The way we're used to

But I change at certain times

> Magnetic north moves, and sometimes the magnetic field flips 180º

Into myself, my thin sibling, into time,

> North to South, South to North

and into ambiguity

> What is it anyway?

or something with which you grasp

> Grasping for guidance

What am I?

> A Magnetic Compass

Answer (score 3):

You see me all day
I'm sharp

> mobile phone

I show you your way
But you show me what to show you

> GPS feature on mobile

I exist, but not in your dimension
I'm made up of down

> Electronic

My older language is by rotation
But now through light

> Older landline (rotations), newer mobile phones (LED touch screen)

(though in the end it comes down to the same shocking tale)

I usually look a certain way
But I change at certain times
Into myself, my thin sibling, into time,
and into ambiguity
or something with which you grasp

> newer thin mobiles

What am I?

> A MOBILE PHONE!!

Comment: This was my thought. I'm still not sure how the "I'm made up of down" line fits though, either for this answer or jhabbot's answer. The best I could come up with is that electrons are negative, which is usually represented as down on a vertical axis. Not that the entire thing is electrons, but electrons are important here. I thought "into myself (then) my thin sibling" was a flip-type, "into time" is a clock, "ambiguity" is the multitude of applications it can be used for, "something you grasp", as opposed to sitting on a desk.

Comment: Thanks. I can add more things to my answer, but don't know how to hide lines and wait for the mouse over to show.

Answer (score 3):

> The Sun. The Sun is always visible during the day. The Sun warps spacetime, and we are always falling towards it, falling down. It shows the way by its position in the sky, by the shadows it casts on a sundial (ok, reaching with that one). The sun looks the same until it sets, rises, or is eclipsed by the moon.